# Can I use Maneuvering Strike benefiting my mount, as a battle master?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, reactions, combat-maneuver, mounted-combat

Here's my scenario, I'm on a mount. I make a weapon attack and use Maneuvering Strike:

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can [...] choose a friendly creature who can see or hear you. That creature can use its reaction to move up to half its speed [...]

Is there anything stopping that creature from being my mount and me going with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### This works.

There really isn’t much to say here. Your mount is a friendly creature that can see or hear you. If it has its reaction available, it may move up to half its speed. If it is a controlled mount, it moves as you direct it, otherwise it moves as it wishes (see the [rules for controlling a mount](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ControllingaMount) for details).