# How to get a ranged bonus action attack before/without attacking or using a combat manoeuvre?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, mounted-combat, action-economy, bonus-action

I want to use [Maneuvering Attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/193476/can-i-use-maneuvering-strike-benefiting-my-mount-as-a-battle-master) to move my mount, and then make an attack action on the creature I move towards. However I want the weapon attack that triggers this combat manoeuvre to be made as a *ranged* weapon attack against the same opponent, and explicitly with my bonus action *prior* to the mounts movement. If you need a reason - it's a cool visual for me.

**I'm assuming no multi-attack/extra attack or action surge**. Just using a straight-forward bonus action and action combination.

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can [...] choose a friendly creature who can see or hear you. That creature can use its reaction to move up to half its speed [...]

I would use Quick Toss:

> As a bonus action, you can expend one superiority die and make a ranged attack with a weapon that has the thrown property. You can draw the weapon as part of making this attack. If you hit, add the superiority die to the weapon’s damage roll.

but I am limited to one manoeuvre per attack:

> You can use only one maneuver per attack.

Similarly [Crossbow Expert](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/crossbow-expert) is [no use](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/122411/2788), as that bonus action attack is *after* using the attack action:

> When you use the Attack action and attack with a one-handed weapon, you can use a bonus action to attack with a hand crossbow you are holding.

If there's multiple ways, I'll pick the lowest level, then fewest character choices (e.g. fewest multiclassing choices, feat choices, spell choices...)

Comment: Related (different limitations): [Is there any way to use a bonus action to fire a Longbow](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95437)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### *Swift Quiver*

The only way I know of to make a ranged weapon attack with you bonus action without it being tied to the Attack action is [*swift quiver*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/swift-quiver):

> On each of your turns until the spell ends, you can use a bonus action to make two attacks with a weapon that uses ammunition from the quiver.

The downside is that it's a 5th level ranger spell, requiring 17 levels in that class (or 10 in the bard class for magical secrets). It's also self only (or as written can only target/benefit your own quiver), so you can't get your friends to help you.

### *Haste*

Perhaps a better option would be [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste). It doesn't actually use your bonus action, but an additional action so you still have your bonus action available afterwards. It's only a 3rd level spell, on multiple class lists and is castable on others so could be cast by one of your allies instead of you.

Comment: Swift Quiver is a good answer!